# Why do we not need to instantiate LayoutInflater in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am new in Android.. so i dont know whether i am asking a stupid question or not.
Anyways here it is..

We know .. we instantiate a object in java like so:

```
Sagar sagarObject = new Sagar();
```

where Sagar is the class

but i just saw a code in android which is:

```
LayoutInfalter sagarsInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
```

where layoutInflater is the class.

Now i am not able to understand the above code. Shouldn't it be like:

```
LayoutInflater sagarsInflater = new LayoutInflater();
```

Why havent we instantiated that object? Why are using this "from" method wihout automatically withgout even instantiatining?

Another Example,

```
View customView = sagarsInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
```

Here also we didnt instantiate the object from the View class like:

```
View customView = new View();
```

Instead we used the method of sagarsInflater that we just made earlier.

Comment: Because `.from` is a static method

Comment: 1. because LayoutInflater needs context to get some informations fx: about Themes ... also it is a factory method - fx: you don't need multiple LayoutInflater instance for the same context ... 2. Those to lines are irrevelant to each other ... in first you are creating(inflating) view from resources in second one you are creating the view programmatically

Answer (score 6):

First of all, even if you think you are asking something very basic, it will never be a stupid question if it is something you don't know.

You should check the docs for better understanding LayoutInflater:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

> Instantiates a layout XML file into its corresponding View objects. **It
>   is never used directly. Instead, use getLayoutInflater() or
>   getSystemService(Class) to retrieve a standard LayoutInflater instance
>   that is already hooked up to the current context and correctly
>   configured for the device you are running on**.

So you have to get an existing instance `LayoutInflater` from the context, not creating a new one. Thats why you can't use something like

```
LayoutInflater inflater = new LayoutInflater();
```

From the docs you find that the correct way of accessing the `LayoutInflater` is:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

But you are using `LayoutInflater.from(Context context)`. If we go to its implementation we find the following code:

```
public static LayoutInflater from(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater LayoutInflater =
            (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (LayoutInflater == null) {
        throw new AssertionError("LayoutInflater not found.");
    }
    return LayoutInflater;
}
```

We can see it is retrieving the layoutInflater from the context passed as argument.

About the way to call that method, it is used like `Class.method` because it is defined as **static**. This means that the method belongs to the class, and not to the instance of the object.

For more info about this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

For understanding the View related question:

You can instantiate an object View like

```
 View view = new View(context);
```

The view instance will be a view object with default attributes and it wont be attached to any parent View. You use this for creating dynamically layouts from code, for example.

Why you use `inflater.inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot);`?

Because you want to inflate a view from an xml layout. And that's what we use the `LayoutInflater` for.

Again, check the docs for a better explanation:

[LayoutInflater inflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean))

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the documentation
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

```
//Obtains the LayoutInflater from the given context.
static LayoutInflater.from(Context context)
```

Its used statically and cant be used alone , the context will return the layout Inflater.

Comment: And what about the View?

Comment: the Inflater bridges the view from Xml to java

Answer (score 0):

`LayoutInflater` is an `abstract class` and cannot be directly instantiated.

`LayoutInflater` and many other system "services" (in the form of `abstract classes` and `interfaces`) come from the `Context` of your activity.

By coming from the "system" you must not concern yourself with the actual implementation of this service; the system may provide different implementations for different situations.

This is more important for some of the other interfaces provided by `Context` e.g. `AudioManager`, `SpeechRecognizer` etc. you can see the list at the documentation for [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

The [`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class by itself is not visually interesting.  It mostly exists to give subclasses lots of "built in" plumbing  (default implementations) for common operations.  I would argue it should also be `abstract`.  You could give it *some* behavior via attaching *handlers* but usually creating a subclass of `View` gives you better control over customization.

Comment: And what about the View?

Comment: updated my answer, plus see some of the other responses.